# calling custom function of jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I have created a simple jquery plugin as follow:

```
$.fn.greenify = function () {
    var color = "green";
    this.css("color", color);

    function getColor() {
        return "green";
    }
};

//calling plugin
$("#test").greenify();
```

What I want to do this to call function getColor() . something like as shown below:

```
var v1 = $("#test").greenify();
var color = v1.getColor();
```

This is certainly not the way to do it. How can I make such call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not idiomatic jQuery to break chainability, this would work:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
   var color="green";
   this.css( "color", color );

   return {
       getColor: function () {
           return "green";
       }
   };
};
```

Comment: just wanted to know, should it be `this.css()` or `$(this).css()` ?

Comment: @PalashMondal `this` will work because it referes to the jquery selection itself. `$(this)` will simply wrap the jquery selection in a jquery selection. The latter would work too but there's no need for it

Comment: @PalashMondal `this` will work  because greenify function is a part of the same object as .css().

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it and both `this` and `$(this)` seems to work!

Comment: Yeah, although performing `$(this)` on `this` in this context is wasteful. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an object that contains the function:

```
return { getColor: someFunction };
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @MattBall's answer, you can maintain chainability by extending the jQuery object you're passed within the plugin context.

```
$.fn.greenify = function () {
    var color = 'green';
    this.getColor = function () {
        return 'green';
    };
    return this;
};

// so this will work:
$('#test').greenify().addClass('used-jquery-method');

// but you won't be able to do it again if you select again:
var color = $('#test').getColor();  // unknown method

// you'll have to cache it instead, and build from the same 'chain'
var element = $('#test').greenify().addClass('used-jquery-method');
var color = element.getColor();
```